# InputAccessoryView inside a UIPageViewController doesn't show by default

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, inputaccessoryview

I've got a pretty typical chat-like screen with an InputAccessoryView that contains a text field in it.  When the screen is initially loaded, the keyboard is hidden, so the text field is at the bottom of the screen.  When the user taps on the text field, the keyboard shows and the InputAccessoryView moves up with the keyboard.

An example is shown here:

[image]

However, if I put that same UIViewController inside a `UIPageViewController`, the InputAccessoryView doesn't appear by default.  It only will appear if the keyboard is forced to appear by tapping on a different text box.

Example here:

[image]

Also, if switching pages, the `InputAccessoryView` disappears again.

The code for setting up the InputAccessoryView looks like so:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var chatInputView: ChatInputView?

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return self.chatInputView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let chatInputView = ChatInputView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 124))
        chatInputView.awakeFromNib()
        self.chatInputView = chatInputView
    }
```

The InputAccessoryView is created via a XIB file, but is pretty standard.

All of the code can be found in https://github.com/SuperTango/InputAccessoryView

There are two commits. The first commit is tagged "not_working", and shows the not working version by having the default ViewController be the UIPageViewController subclass.  The second commit is tagged "working", and merely sets the default ViewController to the ViewController in the images,

Is there any way to make the InputAccessoryView show by default when putting a UIViewController inside a UIPageViewController?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

in order for the `inputAccessoryView` to show up on your `ViewController` you need to set your `ViewController` to be the `firstResponder` and when using the pageViewController you have multiple `ViewControllers`, which means you need to call `self.becomeFirstResponder()` on your `ViewController` whenever it becomes on screen

you may call it after you set the `chatInputView` or in `viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that needs to be done is when you select one of your pages somehow and you call the `setViewControllers([controllers[0].....)`, after that, you just need to do a `controllers[0].becomeFirstResponder()`.

And that's it, works like magic, like it does without the page controller.

Answer (score 0):

In the view controller:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
    
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    resignFirstResponder()
}
```